# "But I guess you couldn’t relate" (Final fantasy vii)

Tags: meaning

> (Upon talking to the man at the back.) NPC: Brrrrrr...... It's terrible. Who'd expect underwear bandits in this day and age? They wiped me out!
>
> (Upon talking to the man in the middle.) NPC: Any idea what happened? All I know is, when I woke up the 3 of us were butt-naked! But I guess you couldn't relate...

Final Fantasy VII script

I can’t understand the meaning of this phrase: But I guess you couldn’t relate

Comment: You should look into the definitions of "relate" and what there didn't help you.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the speaker thinks that "you" are **unable to empathise with someone in the situation** the speaker is describing.

> We woke up butt-naked in the cold, but I guess you've never been robbed and stipped naked so you couldn't understand what that was like for us.